# A good practice to present service level validation errors to the user using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

Are there some good practices to present service layer validation errors using Spring MVC after "shallow" user input validation has been performed using Spring MVC Validators? For example, having this code:

```
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value = "user/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createNewUser(@ModelAttribute("userForm") UserForm userForm, BindingResult result, Model model){
    UserFormValidator validator = new UserFormValidator(); //extending org.springframework.validation.Validator
    validator.validate(userForm, result);

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        model.addAttribute("userForm", userForm);
        return "user/new";
    }

    // here, for example, the user already might exist
    userService.createUser(userForm.getName(), userForm.getPassword());

    return "redirect:user/home";
}
```

While it may seem trivial having this code as an example, it seems to be a delicate story to me when validation at service layer is a complex task. Despite being an absurd scenario, the UserService might take a list of users to create, and if one of them already exists, then the view tier must somehow be notified about which of them is not valid (e.g. does already exist).

I am looking for a good practice how to design a piece of code, which makes it possible to

1) handle validation errors at the service layer having complex data as input, and

2) to present these validation errors to the user

as easy as possible. Any suggestions?

Comment: jeejava.com/spring-service-layer-bean-validation/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The choice is typically exceptions vs. error codes (or response codes), but the best practice, at least Bloch's, is to only use exceptions in exceptional circumstances, which disqualifies them in this situation, since a user picking an existing username isn't unheard of.

The issue in your service call is that you assume `createUser` is an imperative command with no return value. You should think of it as "try to create a user, and give me a result" instead. That result could then be

- an integer code (horrible idea)
- a constant from a shared Result enum (still a bad idea due to maintainability)
- a constant from something more specific like a `UserOperationResult` enum (better idea since you might want to return `USER_ALREADY_EXISTS` both when you create a new user and when you try to modify a user)
- a `UserCreationResult` object that's completely custom to this call (not a good idea because you'll get an explosion of these)
- a `Result<T>` or `UserOperationResult<T>` wrapper object that combines a response code constant (`ResultCode` or `UserOperationResultCode` respectively) and a return value `T`, or a wildcard `?` when there is no return value ... just watch out for pointcuts and the like that don't expect the wrapper)

The beauty of unchecked exceptions is that they avoid all this crap, but they come with their own set of issues. I'd personally stick to the last option, and have had decent luck with it in the past.

Comment: Would you have the controller handle how the `Result` is processed or pass it the View and have it handle it?

Comment: The controller would decide what to do with the service call results, update the model, and the view would render whatever it needs. There are a few reasons; the view knowing about service call enums could mix concerns, the controller might need to make multiple service calls and combine results, the controller could need to operate on a subset of the result payload, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was very helpful. I already did have a similar idea, I only hoped there is some magical Spring way of doing this. Nevertheless, this solution is strightforward and will likely be understood instantly by others who read my code.

Comment: You can use Valid or Validated annotations on your controllers, but once you're at the service layer, Spring stays out of the way to prevent coupling. That being said, you can still use aspects for @Valid (see the method validation support in Hibernate Validator 5) You can also create your own ConstraintValidator for a custom AvailableUsername annotation, check it automatically from the controller, and throw an exception from the service layer if it's violated, but that can also get messy.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to throwing an exception/returning an error code would be to pass the `Errors`  to `userService.createUser()`. The duplicate username check could then be performed at the service level - and any error appended to the `Errors`. This would ensure that all errors (shallow and more complex) could all be collected up and presented to the view at the same time.

So you could rework your controller method slightly:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "user/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createNewUser(@ModelAttribute("userForm") UserForm userForm, BindingResult result, Model model){
    UserFormValidator validator = new UserFormValidator();
    validator.validate(userForm, result);

    // Pass the BindingResult (which extends Errors) to the service layer call
    userService.createUser(userForm.getName(), userForm.getPassword(), result);

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        model.addAttribute("userForm", userForm);
        return "user/new";
    }

    return "redirect:user/home";
}
```

And your `UserServiceImpl` would then check for duplicate users itself - for example:

```
public void createUser(String name, String password, Errors errors) {
    // Check for a duplicate user
    if (userDao.findByName(name) != null) {
        errors.rejectValue("name", "error.duplicate", new String[] {name}, null);
    }

    // Create the user if no duplicate found
    if (!errors.hasErrors()) {
        userDao.createUser(name, password);
    }
}
```

The `Errors` class is part of Spring's validation framework - so although there would be a dependency on Spring, the service layer wouldn't have any dependency on any web related code.

Comment: Upvoted as a valid alternative; I'm not a fan of pushing mutable bookkeeping objects down the call hierarchy, personally. I also wonder if `Errors` will die out in favour of `ConstraintViolation`, since the latter has been standardised as part of the Bean Validation API.

Comment: What if I want to use the service layer with some other presentation layer technology other than Spring MVC in the future, e.g. JSF? The point I mean is that, when the service layer producing paths in the error object like the following, it will make the transision a horror: errors.rejectValue("someList[" + index + "].someValue", "someValue.isEmpty", "Value should not be empty"); . You would have to parse Strings like "someList[5].someValue" manually first, bofore you can pass the proper error message to the JSF view.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar enough with JSF and how it uses Spring's validation framework to be able to comment. The answer has it's pros and cons. The main pro being simplicity. The main con being the coupling to the validation framework in the service layer. If you are planning on switching the presentation layer, then perhaps returning some kind of `Result` may be a better option for you - as Emerson suggested in his answer.

Comment: @Will Keeling: Thank you. I will post my solution to share my results from this discussion.